# How to set products in Stripe Customer Portal

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

I have a Stripe account for a company selling subscriptions on two websites:

- on website A: subscription plans A1, A2, A3 (these are [Products](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/products-prices) in Stripe parlance)
- on website B: subscription plans B1, B2 (also Products)

I would like to use the [Customer Portal](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/customer-portal) to allow the customers of both websites to manage their plan. I would like to show only show the respective plans on the portals created for each website.
Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

I see that we can provide a [configuration](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/sessions/create) built at runtime when creating a portal session, but I don't see how to specify the product set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Customer Portal Configuration object’s [`features.subscription_update.products` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_update-products) to specify the products available in the portal session. This is what that would look like in Python:

```
    stripe.billing_portal.Configuration.create(
        business_profile={
            "headline": None,
            "privacy_policy_url": "https://example.com/privacy",
            "terms_of_service_url": "https://example.com/tod"
        },
        features={
            "subscription_update": {
                "default_allowed_updates": ["price", "quantity", "promotion_code"],
                "enabled": True,
                "products": [
                    {
                        "product": "prod_B1",
                        "prices": [
                            "price_123",
                            "price_456"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "product": "prod_B2",
                        "prices": ["price_789"]
                    },
                ]
            },
            "payment_method_update": {
                "enabled": True
            },
        },
    )
    session = stripe.billing_portal.Session.create(
        customer="cus_123",
        return_url='https://example.com/account',
        configuration=configuration.id
    )
```

Comment: I did not find it when reading the doc because I was not expecting this setting to be so deep down the configuration object. Many thanks!

Comment: Just saved me a bunch of time digging through Stripe's API docs, thanks!!